# Will malloc round up to the nearest page size?

Tags: c, malloc, mmap, brk

I'm not sure if I'm asking a noob question here, but here I go. I also searched a lot for a similar question, but I got nothing.

So, I know how `mmap` and `brk` work and that, regardless of the length you enter, it will round it up to the nearest page boundary. I also know `malloc` uses `brk`/`sbrk` or `mmap` (At least on Linux/Unix systems) but this raises the question: does `malloc` also round up to the nearest page size? For me, a page size is 4096 bytes, so if I want to allocate 16 bytes with `malloc`, 4096 bytes is... a lot more than I asked for.

Comment: On a modern system with `mmap` the allocation system will use it to allocate pages from the OS, but then it *might* only "allocate" a potion of that and give back tot he caller. If there's memory "left over" then it's saved for future allocations.

Comment: Imagine if every allocation in `malloc` was rounded to a page size.  You want to create a binary search tree to store 200,000 words in it.  Then suddenly the node structure for your tree would take up 1GB of RAM, most of which is unused.  At the kernel level, life may be different.  But in userspace, the details of any underlying architecture are mostly handled for us and we can get on with just asking for some memory when we need it without worrying about how it's done.

Comment: The comments in [this code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c) can tell about the overhead involved in the GNU C Library implementation of malloc. YMMV on other platforms, but should be in the same ball-park.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude interesting, I wasn't aware of that

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for the code, I don't think I have enough time to see everything right now but I'll look back at it later.

Comment: It is not noobish to ask questions as such, but what does it tell that you're asking a  question about a hypothesis that could be easily falsified by writing a little code and running it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I wasn't exactly sure _how_ to go about testing it. You example has helped me though, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(void) {
    void *a = malloc(1);
    void *b = malloc(1);
    uintptr_t ua = (uintptr_t)a;
    uintptr_t ub = (uintptr_t)b;
    size_t page_size = getpagesize();

    printf("page size: %zu\n", page_size);
    printf("difference: %zd\n", (ssize_t)(ub - ua));
    printf("offsets from start of page: %zu, %zu\n",
        (size_t)ua % page_size, (size_t)ub % page_size);
}
```

prints

```
page_size: 4096
difference: 32
offsets from start of page: 672, 704
```

So clearly it is not rounded to page size in **this** case, which proves that it is **not always** rounded to page size.

---

It will hit `mmap` if you change allocation to some arbitrary large size. For example:

```
void *a = malloc(10000001);
void *b = malloc(10000003);
```

and I get:

```
page size: 4096
difference: -10002432
offsets from start of page: 16, 16
```

And clearly the starting address is still not page aligned; the bookkeeping must be stored *below* the pointer *and* the pointer needs to be sufficiently aligned for the largest alignment generally needed - you can reason this with `free` - if `free` is just given a pointer but it needs to figure out the size of the allocation, where could it look for it, and only two choices are feasible: in a separate data structure that lists all base pointers and their allocation sizes, or at some offset *below* the current pointer. And only one of them is *sane*.

Comment: Thank you for the useful example. I'm not sure how exactly it doesn't if `mmap` and `brk` do, but it could be due to what @Someprogrammerdude said. Either way, this answers my question.

Comment: Ah yes, the edits add some more information. Thanks a lot, this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The basic job of malloc and friends is to manage the fact that the OS can generally only (efficiently) deal with large allocations (whole pages and extents of pages), while programs often need smaller chunks and finer-grained management.

So what malloc (generally) does, is that the first time it is called, it allocates a larger amount of memory from the system (via mmap or sbrk -- maybe one page or maybe many pages), and uses a small amount of that for some data structures to track the heap use (where the heap is, what parts are in use and what parts are free) and then marks the rest of that space as free.  It then allocates the memory you requested from that free space and keeps the rest available for subsequent malloc calls.

So the first time you call malloc for eg 16 bytes, it will uses mmap or sbrk to allocate a large chunk (maybe 4K or maybe 64K or maybe 16MB or even more) and initialize that as mostly free and return you a pointer to 16 bytes somewhere.  A second call to malloc for another 16 bytes will just return you another 16 bytes from that pool -- no need to go back to the OS for more.

As your program goes ahead mallocing more memory it will just come from this pool, and free calls will return memory to the free pool.  If it generally allocates more than it frees, eventually that free pool will run out, and at that point, malloc will call the system (mmap or sbrk) to get more memory to add to the free pool.

This is why if you monitor a process that is allocating and freeing memory with malloc/free with some sort of process monitor, you will generally just see the memory use go up (as the free pool runs out and more memory is requested from the system), and generally will not see it go down -- even though memory is being freed, it generally just goes back to the free pool and is not unmapped or returned to the system.  There are some exceptions -- particularly if very large blocks are involved -- but generally you can't rely on any memory being returned to the system until the process exits.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense, I hadn't realized the extra work that goes into implementing malloc.